# You have an error in your SQL syntax; With python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

This is my python code:

```
address_text_list = ["Electricty Substation ,Slagrove Place", "65 Slagrove Place, London", "66 Slagrove Place, London Parking Space", "61 Slagrove Place, London", "67 Slagrove Place, London"
                     , "169 Mersham Road, Thornton Heath", "171 Mersham Road, Thornton Heath", "The Ground Floor Flat At 5 Lugard Road,", "First Floor Flat, 5 Lugard Road, London"
                     , "Flat 1, 203 Coldharbour Lane, London"]

for x in range(len(address_text_list)-1):
    update = "INSERT INTO Property_details (Property_address) VALUE (%s)"
    update2 = (address_text_list[x])
    mycursor.execute (update, update2)
    db.commit()
```

I have tried to make a python code that updates the database "Property_details" in the column "Property_address" with a MySQL database using python.
This is the error I am getting:

```
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Work/Web Scraping/Selenium/EIG properties.py", line 659, in <module>
    mycursor.execute (update, update2)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Work\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Work\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Work\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: I assume you're trying to do prepared statements? Your placeholder should be `?` rather than `%s`. See if that works.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun Thanks for the answer, I tried it, and it still doesn't work!

Comment: @nerya, you don't need the `range`. Just iterate the value directly. And according to your code, the last one will be missing.

Comment: Let me post my answer.

Comment: Try to add comma like update2 = (address_text_list[x],)

Comment: @nerya, I posted an improved answer.

Comment: The second parameter of `execute` must be a tuple. Don't construct your SQL string manually as some of the answers suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
address_text_list = [
    "Electricty Substation ,Slagrove Place", "65 Slagrove Place, London",
    "66 Slagrove Place, London Parking Space", "61 Slagrove Place, London",
    "67 Slagrove Place, London" , "169 Mersham Road, Thornton Heath",
    "171 Mersham Road, Thornton Heath", "The Ground Floor Flat At 5 Lugard Road,",
    "First Floor Flat, 5 Lugard Road, London", "Flat 1, 203 Coldharbour Lane, London"]

for address in address_text_list:
    query = 'INSERT INTO `Property_details` (Property_address) VALUE ("%s")' % address
    mycursor.execute(query)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Back to SQL injection we go. Welcome [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/).